# Parsing date with milliseconds in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to parse dates with this format 2016-07-27 04:45:33.881000000

into d3.js using

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L");
```

but it doesn't work, if I remove the milliseconds from the data it does work using this

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

I got the .%L from the documentation, any idea why it might not be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this to work, not exactly your issue. %L only takes a 3 digit integer

%L - milliseconds as a decimal number [000, 999].
https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#utcParse

```
var d3 = require('d3');

var dateString = '2016-07-27 04:45:33.881';

var parseTime = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L");

console.log(parseTime(dateString));
```

Comment: Oh, so the data source showing the millseconds with too many number is the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Also: consider using %f instead of %L

Answer (score 0):

The way I got it worked is by using 3 %L for 9 integer values of milliseconds shown below:

var date= "2019-02-19T00:00:00.0000000-04:00"

'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%L%L%Z'